# Why can't I force cast an NSManagedObject in my Core Data unit test?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, core-data

I have a simple entity called 'Lift' and this simple unit test:

```
func testLiftEntityCreation() {
    let lift = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Lift", into: managedObjectContext) as! Lift

    Logger.coreData.debug("The object is of type \(type(of: lift))")
    XCTAssertNotNil(lift)
    XCTAssertTrue(lift.isKind(of: Lift.self))
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Test Case '-[My_App_Tests.LiftTests testLiftEntityCreation]' started.
Could not cast value of type 'My_App.Lift' (0x6000029190b8) to 'My_App_Tests.Lift' (0x10f220df8).
2023-10-30 18:19:41.867620-0700 My_App[12267:1392673] Could not cast value of type 'My_App.Lift' (0x6000029190b8) to 'My_App_Tests.Lift' (0x10f220df8).
```

If I remove the cast, it runs but the test fails even though the object is of type Lift:

```
Test Case '-[My_App_Tests.LiftTests testLiftEntityCreation]' started.
2023-10-30 18:23:31.429225-0700 My_App[12291:1398106] [coredata] The object is of type Lift
../LiftTests.swift:20: error: -[My_App_Tests.LiftTests testLiftEntityCreation] : XCTAssertTrue failed
```

I confirmed that I'm importing my app correctly:

```
import XCTest
import CoreData
@testable import My_App
```

I've read the three SO questions I could find that are related to this issue and have confirmed that the class name in the Data Model Inspector is 'Lift' and Codegen is set to Class Definition.

1. Why is the cast failing?
2. When I remove the cast, why does it fail when my debug statement confirms that it is of type 'Lift'?

Comment: make sure you are using testable import instead of assigning all the files to the test target

Comment: I did that too. Thanks for the tip though, @loremipsum.

Comment: Note that's `My_App.Lift` vs `My_App_Tests.Lift`, it considers that's two different class `Lift`, that's why. It seems you fixed the issue, but we could think that's a "miss/wrong import" that makes it thinks that they are different while they should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that somehow my .xcdatamodeld was in my test target's list of compile sources. Once I removed it, I was able to run the version of the test that force casts the object to a 'Lift' and it passes.